# What is the difference between ASP.NET Web Pages and Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, webforms, asp.net-webpages

Is "Web Pages" just another name for "Razor"? Or has is added new features to the "Razor" which has been used since ASP.NET MVC3?

If Web Pages is a new thing besides ASP.NET WebForm and MVC, how can I create a "Web Pages" project in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, Razor is just syntax that provides a fast, approachable, and lightweight way to combine server code with HTML to create dynamic web content. If you want to create a "Web Pages" project in Visual Studio, then follow the steps that are described in the tutorial [Program ASP.NET Web Pages in Visual Studio](https://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/program-asp-net-web-pages-in-visual-studio). This will give you detailed information on the step by step creation of Web pages project in visual studio including screenshots which will make your process easier.

Answer (score 2):

Web Pages is like Web Forms but with razor syntax.

Razor is the syntax used on the view pages (.cshtml is the razor extension).